# How to convert 119.305.1983984.1 to 1.1983984.305.119 in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have to convert `119.305.1983984.1` to `1.1983984.305.119` in SQL Server.

I have tried as shown below using `reverse`, but it does not work

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(20);  
SET @myvar = '119.305.1983984.1';  
SELECT REVERSE(@myvar) AS Reversed ;  
GO
```

The result is `1.4893891.503.911`
Expected result is `1.1983984.305.119`

I do not want to be reversed.just want last to first showed: `1.1983984.305.119`.

Comment: Why you declare the variable as varchar(10) and assign more than 10 chars?

Comment: First you say you want to go from 305.1983984.1 to 1.1983984.305.119, then the code has 119.305.1983984.1...

Comment: i want write last to first 1.1983984.305.119
first to last : 119.305.1983984.1
last to first : 1.1983984.305.119

Comment: This is really something better handled in your application/outside layer.  You are trying to do a complex manipulation of what should be ideally a somewhat immutable single point of data in SQL Server.

Comment: Are the number of parts constant, and is the separator always a period? This happens to be something you can abuse `PARSENAME` for: `SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME(@myvar, 1), '.', PARSENAME(@myvar, 2), '.', PARSENAME(@myvar, 3), '.', PARSENAME(@myvar, 4))` (assuming you up the length of `@myvar` so it can actually hold the string, of course).

Comment: Try something using the function `STRING_SPLIT` passing a dot as the separator

Comment: @RobertKock There is [no way](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/207274/5203) with `string_split` to guarantee the order of chunks. When you glue it back, there will be no column to order by.

Comment: @GSerg you're right. I missed that part. Forget my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If number of tokens is known and it is up to four (SQL Server 2012+)**:

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(20);  
SET @myvar = '119.305.1983984.1';  

SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME(@myvar,1),'.',PARSENAME(@myvar,2),'.',PARSENAME(@myvar,3),'.',PARSENAME(@myvar,4))
```

Original value: **119.305.1983984.1**

SELECT returns: **1.1983984.305.119**

---

**If number of tokens is varying and SQL Server is 2017+ :**

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(20), @separator CHAR(1)  
SET @myvar = '119.305.1983984.1';  
SET @separator = '.'


SELECT STRING_AGG(value, @separator)  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY rn DESC ) 
FROM (
    SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0) ) rn
    FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @myvar , @separator )  
) d OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

SELECT returns: **1.1983984.305.119**

Comment: This should come with caveats: the number of parts must be exactly 4, the separator must be a period, and the parts cannot include the special characters `[`, `]` or `"`. Deviating from any of that will make this fail in more or less interesting ways.

Comment: I think OP want to reverse whole string and your query will work for definite number of dot (.) only. It will not reverse in either case when number of dot (.)  increases or decreases. Also it will not run in lower version of SQL Server but that is not a case.

Comment: @Suraj: `PARSENAME` is available since at least SQL Server 2005 (and I'm pretty sure it's actually older than that). `CONCAT` has only been available since SQL Server 2012, but the use here is elective -- `+` works just as well. Whatever other problems this approach has, compatibility isn't one of them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert As have already mentioned that Concat is not working however not an issue already written but when the number of dot will either increase or decrease then it will not work properly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, indeed the number of tokens should be up to 4 to leverage parsename. SQL Server 2017 gives more options to get desired result in more or less elegant way.

Comment: It should probably be noted that while in reality you are probably going to get the expected result with the `order by (select 0)`, it is not actually guaranteed, and it is theoretically possible that due to quirks of implementation / parallelism the chunks will be numbered not in expected order.

Comment: @GSerg, thanks, good point, on large datasets it can be a case. The query is adjusted, MAXDOP 1 added

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(17) = '119.305.1983984.1'; --It's 17 not 10

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Value, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@myvar, '.')
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(Value, '.') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RN DESC)
FROM CTE;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------------------+
| 1.1983984.305.119 |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: no i want get 1.1983984.305.119 but this code 1.4893891.503.911

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query as shown below. This will run any versions of Sql server and no need to pass hard value like `1, 2 or n` for position.

```
Declare @test varchar(max)
Set @test = '119.305.1983984.1'

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+'.' ,'') + Convert(Varchar(10), IpAddress)
from (
Select 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN,  T2.item.value('(./text())[1]','int') as IpAddress
from
     (select convert(xml,'<items><t>'+replace(@test,'.','</t><t>')+'</t></items>') as xmldoc)
as xmltable
     CROSS APPLY xmltable.xmldoc.nodes('/items/t') as T2(item)      
)a order by RN desc

select @listStr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a split function through a Delimiter `(.)`. Then all values turn into a table. By ROW_NUMBER() function you can define a number along with all items to REVERSE them. Finally, you can use `COALESCE` to concatenate them.

**split function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@Delimiter varchar(5), @List varchar(8000) ) 
RETURNS @TableOfValues table 
(  Value varchar(50)   ) 
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @LenString int 

WHILE len( @List ) > 0 
    BEGIN 

    SELECT @LenString = 
        (CASE charindex( @Delimiter, @List ) 
            WHEN 0 THEN len( @List ) 
            ELSE ( charindex( @Delimiter, @List ) -1 )
        END
        ) 

    INSERT INTO @TableOfValues 
        SELECT substring( @List, 1, @LenString )

    SELECT @List = 
        (CASE ( len( @List ) - @LenString ) 
            WHEN 0 THEN '' 
            ELSE right( @List, len( @List ) - @LenString - 1 ) 
        END
        ) 
    END
    RETURN 
END
```

**OUTPUT Query**

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(20);  
SET @myvar = '119.305.1983984.1';
Declare @val Varchar(MAX);
Select @val = COALESCE(@val + '.' + Value, Value) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT Value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as number from [dbo].[Split]('.',@myvar)
    ) AS T ORDER BY number DESC
SELECT @val;
```

**OUTPUT**
1.1983984.305.119